# Local Azure Function Shutting Down Automatically

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm working on an building an HTTP trigger Azure function in PowerShell using VS Code and the Azure Functions extension. I've been able to get the function to run and I can send a request to it but for some reason after exactly 30 seconds the function shut's down. Below is what the functions runtime seems to output every time

```
> Executing task: func host start <

                  %%%%%%
                 %%%%%%
            @   %%%%%%    @
          @@   %%%%%%      @@
       @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
     @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
       @@         %%%%       @@
         @@      %%%       @@
           @@    %%      @@
                %%
                %

Azure Functions Core Tools (2.7.1585 Commit hash: 9a2b7239b937148e3b76e6f7999798629a82134a)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12641.0
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] Building host: startup suppressed:False, configuration suppressed: False
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] Initializing Host.
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] LoggerFilterOptions
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] {
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "MinLevel": "None",
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "Rules": [
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]     {
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "ProviderName": null,
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "CategoryName": null,
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "LogLevel": null,
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]     },
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]     {
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "CategoryName": null,
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "LogLevel": "None",
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "Filter": null
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]     },
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]     {
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "CategoryName": null,
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "LogLevel": null,
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]     }
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   ]
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] }
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] {
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "BatchSize": 1000,
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "IsEnabled": true
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] }
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] SingletonOptions
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] {
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] }
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] HttpOptions
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] {
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
[9/4/2019 14:47:37]   "RoutePrefix": "api"
[9/4/2019 14:47:37] }
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Starting JobHost
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Starting Host (HostId=9s716j112276zf8-796082477, InstanceId=50750694-8516-4056-9c4e-25b05eed3725, Version=2.0.12641.0, ProcessId=10452, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=)
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Loading functions metadata
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] 1 functions loaded
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Loading proxies metadata
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Initializing Azure Function proxies
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] 0 proxies loaded
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Starting language worker process:dotnet  "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\powershell\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.dll" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 50001 --workerId 91f57cdd-3cea-40cf-96da-5ff31d3b3854 --requestId c430cb96-2989-4e61-a64e-e7b339bad0bf --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] dotnet process with Id=18768 started
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Generating 1 job function(s)
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Found the following functions:
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Host.Functions.newusername
[9/4/2019 14:47:38]
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Host initialized (775ms)
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Host started (794ms)
[9/4/2019 14:47:38] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\powershell
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Http Functions:

        newusername: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/newusername

[9/4/2019 14:47:39] System Log: { Log-Level: Information; Log-Message: The enforced concurrency level (pool size limit) is '1'. }
[9/4/2019 14:47:39] System Log: { Log-Level: Trace; Log-Message: Custom pipe name specified. You can attach to the process by using vscode or by running `Enter-PSHostProcess -CustomPipeName AzureFunctionsPSWorker` }
[9/4/2019 14:47:43] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000020C6A659'.
```

It sits at this and responds to requests to the address but after almost exactly 30 seconds it shuts down. My question is if anyone knows why it is automatically shutting down the function and how to stop it from doing so

My host.json file looks like

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "managedDependency": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  This is happening to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe caused by your `host.json` file.

Your problem seems come from this:
[image]

Can you show your `host.json` file?

The default host.json file is:

```
{
    "version": "2.0"
}
```

If it still doesn't work, please show more details. Have you do something with the template?

Comment: I've posted the host.json file contents in the original post. Interestingly enough, without changing anything now vscode seems to be attaching to the function and running indefinitely until I disconnect the debugger